# Transform column data from GB to TB using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df, that has many columns. One of the columns holds values, GB, that I wish to convert to TB.

```
   ID      Total_Capacity           Partial_Capacity TB

   A       5 TB                     729.8 GB
   B       10 TB                    829.1 GB
```

Desired outcome:

```
   ID      Total_Capacity           Partial_Capacity TB

   A       5 TB                     0.7298 
   B       10 TB                    0.8291
```

1000 Gigabytes = 1 Terabyte.

I am thinking of creating a function, however, is there a way to set the conversion formula to a particular column within a dataframe?

```
  Def Bytes(B):

  If GB <= B < TB:
  return '{0:.2f} GB'.format(B/GB)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/ont-opic].

Comment: Yes, I have done a lot of research. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `regex` remove the `space` and `alphas` after `digits`, convert outcome to float and divide by 1000

```
df['Partial_Capacity TB']=df['Partial_Capacity TB'].str.replace('\s\w+','').astype(float).div(1000)



 ID Total_Capacity  Partial_Capacity  TB  Partial_Capacity TB
A   5             TB             729.8  GB               0.7298
B  10             TB             829.1  GB               0.8291
```